# Django inline objects not getting saved

Tags: django, django-admin

Can anyone who tell us where is the code for django to save the inline form objects in admin site?

I've got an issue that the django does not pick up the field I typed in in an inline form. I think I should overwrite the save method somewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline formsets are saved here: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L678

Called from both `add_view` and `change_view` in the same file.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the problem itself -- the second sentence is too ambiguous; perhaps post your code and describe the problem in detail?